# Meteor + React - Session Variable not behaving reactively

Tags: session, meteor, reactjs

I'm new to the community but I kept searching for one week on it to see if my question was answered before but apparently not much is relating to meteor 1.4 with react.

So I'm building an app (I'm new to Meteor + React) that reads a huge XML file stored on the server and then needs to extract some data from it, display it and then launch some other functions with that acquired data on different pages so I thought it was a good idea to store this XML parsed into a JSON Object into a session variable but then immediately the problems started as the first simple data extraction doesn't behave reactively.

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

FlightPlan = new Mongo.Collection("flightPlan");

export default class FlightPlanWrapper extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  xmlDemo(){
    Meteor.call('xmlDemo',function(error,flightPlanXML){
      let tempXML = flightPlanXML;
      Session.set({
        'flightPlanXML': flightPlanXML
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const flightNumber = Session.get('flightPlanXML') ? (
      <span className="flightNumber">{Session.get('flightPlanXML').FlightPlan.FlightInfo.aTCCallsign}</span>
    ) : '';

    return (
      <div id='flightPlan' className='contentWrapper'>
        <h2>
          Flight Plan
        </h2>

        {
          Session.get('flightPlanXML') ? flightNumber :
            <div>
              <button onClick={this.xmlDemo.bind(this)}>click me</button>
            </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default createContainer (() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('flightPlan');
  return {
    'resolutions': FlightPlan.find().fetch()
  };
}, FlightPlanWrapper);
```

So I'm not sure if my understanding of the system is correct at all but what I would like to do in this simplified version of the code is to either display the button or the content of that session variable.

Please note that when I change page after having clicked the button and then I come back to the same page the content is updated properly.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to break the code having the flight number output on one file called (FlightPlanContent.jsx) and the button on another file (FlightPlanForm.jsx). <br/>

I then make the call in (FlightPlanWrapper.jsx) render this way:

`{Session.get('flightPlanXML') ? <FlightPlanContent flightData={Session.get('flightPlanXML')}/> : <FlightPlanForm />}`

but the result is still the same: the output is not reactive, it changes only after I change page (not a refresh as it would dump the session variable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Meteor + React, all reactive Meteor data sources (such as DB collection `find` calls and `Session.get`) need to be within `createContainer`. So you need to do this:

```
export default createContainer (() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('flightPlan');
  return {
    'resolutions': FlightPlan.find().fetch(),
    flightPlan: Session.get('flightPlanXML')
  };
}, FlightPlanWrapper);
```

Then you can use `this.props.fightPlan` from within the render function.

Note that this is not reactive in the sense that if the content of your XML file changes on the server, the changes are not reflected in the UI. If this is what you want, I would recommend you to write a script on the server that extracts the data from the XML and writes it to the Mongo database for Meteor to use like any other DB data.

**Clarification as requested by Cod3Citrus**

To understand why this is necessary, you must understand that React reactivity and Meteor reactivity are two different things. React reactivity works so that when, and only when, the `props` or `state` of a component changes, its `render` function is re-run. Meteor reactivity works so that when a *reactive data source*, such as `collection.find` or `Session.get`, that is called *within a reactive context* changes value, this reactive context is re-run. Examples of Meteor reactive contexts are `Tracker.autorun` and the data function passed to `createContainer`. Thus **placing Meteor-reactive data sources (`Session.get`) within React-reactive `render` function will not work**.

Comment: This worked for me. @Waiski, could you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: @Cod3Citrus I updated the answer with a small clarification. I hope that clears it up :)